# overflow-y not working with fixed position

Tags: html, css

I try to make div with `height: 100%;` but background needs to have a fixed position.

I tried to use `box-sizing:border-box;` like someone answer on a similar question like my, but this is not working for me. Also, I tried to use absolute position, but still the same.

Here is my css

```
.backgroundIdKlupa {
position:fixed;
padding: 0;
z-index: 999999;
margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.backgroundIdKlupa_tablica {
background-color: grey;
top: 0;
bottom:0;
position:fixed;
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
.idKlupa_tablica {
height: 90%;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold; 
margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.backgroundIda {
background-color: green;
width: 100%;
height: 550px;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="backgroundIdKlupa col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <table class="backgroundIdKlupa_tablica table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="backgroundIdKlupa_izbornik_th">Bench ID</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>   
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="aktivniItem backgroundIdKlupa_izbornik_td" >123</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="aktivniItem backgroundIdKlupa_izbornik_td" >123</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="aktivniItem backgroundIdKlupa_izbornik_td" >123</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody> 
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="backgroundIda col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
```

Left menu needs to be fixed, but if there is more item, need to have overflow-y: auto

Right content (green) is regular. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For add scroll in any element you need to add height or max-height. second this is a table so make it a block element by using display:block

backgroundIdKlupa_tablica {
    background-color: grey;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanke you  Ankit Awasthi. This work, but for height I need to add  height: 100%; but with percent not working.

Comment: .backgroundIdKlupa_tablica {
      background-color: grey;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    }                                                                                                                   Working for me here just add plenty of row in table